# Way to convert an overloaded function into a tuple of function pointers

Tags: c++, tuples, c++14, overloading, function-pointers

Suppose I have an overloaded function set like so:

```
void foo(int);
void foo(float);
void foo(double);
```

What I want to do is create a tuple of function pointers to each of the functions:

```
auto ptrs = std::make_tuple(static_cast<void (*)(int)>(foo),
                            static_cast<void (*)(float)>(foo),
                            static_cast<void (*)(double)>(foo));
```

But I want to not have to specify each of the overloads.....What I really want is to say something like this:

```
auto ptrs = magic_function(foo);
```

Where `magic_function` somehow figures out what all the overloads are and acts upon that information.......

Is this possible, or is this wishful thinking?

Comment: I suppose wishful thinking... but I'll wait to see if someone can do it.

Comment: @DarthRubik: *I was looking for something that would somehow determine that there where three overloads and generate a tuple of function pointers to each of the functions* i,e: you want the compiler or `magic_function()` to find all the overloads of `foo()` and `std::make_tuple` of all of them, right? Just for clarity.

Comment: @JeJo Correct...

Comment: @DarthRubik Hmm... Out of bounds to my head.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do this in C++ yet. Not only that, but I don't think any of the overload set proposals will let you do it either. I'm not even sure if the reflection proposal will let you do it.

Comment: @Brian I figured as much....but I had to try

Comment: The reflection TS is still to be done: https://isocpp.org/std/status